# How to get similar result as if Thread.Sleep were supports double values?

Tags: c#, multithreading, double, sleep, milliseconds

Sometimes I need to sleep non integer amount of milliseconds, but can't find a way to do so.
For example, if I want to sleep half of millisecond, I want to do this:

```
Thread.Sleep(0.5);
```

But can't, since Sleep supports integers only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your timings are so important than you are using entirely wrong tool for the job because

> Thread.Sleep(n) means blocking the current thread for at least the
>   number of timeslices (or thread quantums) that can occur within n
>   milliseconds. The length of a timeslice is different on different
>   versions/types of Windows and different processors and generally
>   ranges from 15 to 30 milliseconds. This means the thread is almost
>   guaranteed to block for more or than n milliseconds on different
>   computers. The likelihood that your thread will re-awaken exactly
>   after n milliseconds is about as impossible as impossible can be. So,
>   Thread.Sleep is pointless for timing.

You can read all about this [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx).

**Note:** If you post the problem you are trying to address with

> Thread.Sleep

we might be able to guide you in the right direction

Comment: +1 I agree with you. `Thread.Sleep` does not guarantee exact timing.

Comment: Thank you. I guess, I will just use Thread.Sleep(1) then, if I need to sleep less than that. I simulating physical device measures sequence, that going to be displayed at chart after (example is measuring of pH, Conductivity, Ampere and etc). You can scale chart for a very large percentage, so even milliseconds can be visible. Person can set different device ask frequency, so I wanted the values on chart would be time separated on same amount of milliseconds, as user set. But if this is not easy, I can live with 1 ms limit. However, still good to find out how to sleep float amount of ms.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep` does not support non integer values for milliseconds because it does not have sub-millisecond resolution. In fact, the resolution is probably going to be much higher than 1 millisecond (probably 15ms or even higher depending on hardware). I suspect the API designers took that into account when deciding on the data type.

By the way, there two special cases.

`Thread.Sleep(0)` - This will cause the thread to yield to another thread with the same or higher priority.

`Thread.Sleep(1)` - This will cause the thread to yield to any thread regardless of priority.